# Can I color different months?

Tags: python, pandas

My data has a datetime index.  I've  resampled the data and want to visualize it so that the different months all have a different color.  Here is my data

```
Time        Count
2016-08-07  88
2016-08-14  95
2016-08-21  86
2016-08-28  81
2016-09-04  92
2016-09-11  89
2016-09-18  93
2016-09-25  83
2016-10-02  78
2016-10-09  90
2016-10-16  87
2016-10-23  79
2016-10-30  91
2016-11-06  90
2016-11-13  87
2016-11-20  97
2016-11-27  83
2016-12-04  63
```

How can I plot this data so that each month has a different color?

Comment: Do you use `bash` terminal ?

Comment: What kind of plot you want to use?

Comment: If you want to plot pandas dates in matplotlib try this:
[Plot pandas dates in matplotlib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25416955/plot-pandas-dates-in-matplotlib)

Comment: @Bonifacio2 preferably a bar plot. I want each bar belonging to a seperate month to have all the same color (so fo rinstance, all the November bars are blue)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per request for "each bar belonging to a seperate month to have all the same color".  You can change the colours to whatever you like in the dict below and these are then used in the list comprehension.

```
df['month'] = df.index.to_datetime().month

colors = {8: 'r', 9: 'b', 10: 'g',11: 'y', 12: 'w',}
df['Count'].plot(kind='bar', color=[colors[i] for i in df['month']])
```

[image]

Comment: I would add `rot=45` to view the x-axis better.

Answer (score 0):

This is not for a plot (I have added that below) but you can also color your dataframe text output if this is of interest.  I find it can help me identify groups of data.

I created a new  `df['month']` column and you can see the function I applied below to give you color for your months using [style](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html).

```
df['month'] = df.index.to_datetime().month

def color_monthd(val):

    color = 'blue' if val == 8\
    else 'orange' if val == 9\
    else 'purple' if val == 10\
    else 'red' if val == 11\
    else 'black'

    return 'color: %s' % color

s = df.style.applymap(color_monthd)
```

[image]