# Stacked chart colors based on column name in Python

Tags: python, pandas, plot, colors, mapping

I have a pandas dataframe (timeseries) with multiple columns representing different sources of power generation (e.g. coal, nuclear, gas). I would like for the data in each column/category to be displayed in a specific color based on the column name.

My thought is is to have a list used to map a pre-defined color to the column/category names (coal, nuclear etc.) and then refer to that list when generating a stacked chart.

Is there a way to do this or am I at the mercy of python limitations (unlikely...)?

Comment: Your idea is fine, go for it

Comment: You can do something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41526689/can-i-color-different-months/41527152#41527152

Comment: @ade1e problem is that my dataframe has multiple columns which I am plotting like this: `ax = df.ix[plotstart:plotend].plot(stacked=True, kind='area', figsize=(16, 8))` and this does not allow me to crate a loop