# Problem setting major xticks for years on x-axis in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

With the following code, I was hoping for the major ticks on the X-axis to display the years '2014,2015...2019'.
I have tried plt.xticks(dates) and ax.tick_params. Yet, nothing appears.
Then I have tried to add  xticks=merged.index ( as the years are the index in my df), and I got '0006' x ticks?!

```
ax=merged.plot(kind='line', xticks=merged.index,marker='o',figsize=(9,6),legend=None, color=my_colors, ax=ax)
```

I do not have this problem with the Y-axis ticks.

Where I am going wrong?  I am not getting any error messages.

You can try to run my full code (below) ..

(this is my line chart without the x ticks) [image: my line chart].

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# read all the tables from the web
all_df_lists = []
for year in range(2014, 2020):
    url='http://www.svpl.org.uk/index.php/{}-league-tables?year={}-league-tables'.format(year, year)
    all_df_lists.append(pd.read_html(url))

#Processing data
desired_columns = ['Year', 'TblNbr', 'Rank', 'Teams', 'Played', 'Points', 'GD', 'PD']
for year, df_list in zip(range(2014, 2020), all_df_lists):
    for i, df in enumerate(df_list):
        df['Year'] = year
        df['TblNbr'] = i
        for col in desired_columns:
            if not col in df.columns:
                df[col] = np.nan
                print("added column {} to table {} of year {}".format(col, i, year))
desired_columns

df_combined = pd.concat([df[desired_columns] for df_list in all_df_lists for df in df_list], ignore_index=True)
df_combined.head()

merged=df_combined[(df_combined.values == 'Alveley Oaks')|(df_combined.values == 'Kinver Con Club')|(df_combined.values == 'Nomads')|(df_combined.values == 'Kinver Con Club')|(df_combined.values == 'Top Pub')|(df_combined.values == 'Plough')|(df_combined.values == 'Alveley Royals')|(df_combined.values == 'Footloose')|(df_combined.values == "Gaters 'A'")|(df_combined.values == 'Alveley Oaks')]
merged=merged.pivot_table(index='Year', columns='Teams',values='Points').reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
merged=merged.set_index('Year')
merged

# Plotting the line chart
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FixedLocator, FormatStrFormatter
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
%matplotlib notebook
plt.style.use('seaborn-poster')

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6), facecolor='w', edgecolor='blue')

ax.set_ylim(-0.7, 31)  

# trying to display the years as ticks on x-axis.
dates = pd.date_range('01-01-2014', periods=6, freq='A')
plt.xticks(dates)

ax = plt.gca()
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(reset=True)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator(1))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y'))

ax.get_xaxis().tick_bottom()
ax.get_yaxis().tick_left()

ax.tick_params(axis='y', which='major', labelsize=12, bottom=False, top=False, labelbottom=False,
               left=True, right=False, labelright=False)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', labelsize=14, bottom=True, top=False, labelbottom=True,
               left=False, right=False, labelright=False)


ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)

#plt.margins(x=0.015,y=0.05)


x_axis = ax.axes.get_xaxis()
x_label = x_axis.get_label()
x_label.set_visible(False)
ax.set_ylabel('Points won', color='darkblue',  fontdict={'fontsize': 14, 'fontweight': 'medium'})
my_colors=['orangered','seagreen','darkred' , 'darkviolet', 'steelblue','teal', 'springgreen', 'sienna']

ax=merged.plot(kind='line', marker='o',figsize=(9,6),legend=None, color=my_colors, ax=ax)

for line, name in zip(ax.lines, merged.columns):

    y = line.get_ydata()[-1]
    ax.annotate(name, xy=(0.984,y), xytext=(6,0), color=line.get_color(), 
                xycoords = ax.get_yaxis_transform(), textcoords="offset points",
                size=14, va="center")


ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.FuncFormatter('{:.0f}'.format))
ax.grid(True, 'major', 'y', ls='--', lw=.7, c='darkgray', alpha=.5)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Pandas has its own interpretation of how dates and time differences have to look. Here it's hard to intervene with matplotlib functionality, except if you convert the dates to matplotlib format (and don't use pandas for plots depending on them). As your example code doesn't create a full plot (only the embellishments), it's hard to guess what you want to draw. Note that pandas e.g. interprets bar plots different as line plots when it comes to dates.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plot pandas dates in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25416955/plot-pandas-dates-in-matplotlib)

Comment: I excluded the code for my chart (df.plot...) however, it is very much the same. No x-ticks appear, as you can see from my screenshot.

Comment: I have just copied my full code here for you to see.. how do I go about converting the dates to matplotlib format? I have tried #merged.Year = pd.to_datetime(merged['Year'], format='%Y.%f') and it did not help me. thank  you.

Comment: You're not using dates to plot, it are just numbers that happen to be years. Just the default xticks will do well.  Or maybe `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))` if you want to make extra sure to get a tick at every year.

Comment: The root of the problem is involving mdates when you're only working with numbers that happen to be years. Just leave out all references to mdates. Don't use `plt.xticks(dates)`

Comment: I have solved it! I used merged.Year = pd.to_datetime(merged['Year'], format='%Y') in my dataframe and then  dates = pd.date_range('01-01-2014', periods=6, freq='A')
plt.xticks(dates) for my plot. thank you.